# Is it okay to run a query in a PHP class constructor?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

This is my first go at creating an object oriented site in PHP and a question regarding constructors.

I have a character class that is generated after a user logs in. The character object will hold all the user data for the game.

My question is regarding the constructor / instantiating the class. Would it be okay to run a query in the class constructor like I have in the attached code?

Currently the argument being passed in is just the username which is obtained during login and that is what is ran in the query to get the character info.

Would this be okay or best practice be to run the query outside the construct or class and pass in the arguments to the classes constructor?

Just want to make sure I am not overlooking any potential issues with the current code I have - As long as exceptions are accounted for it should be okay to keep the query in the constructor, no?

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/rx/includes/classes/connection.php";

class Character {
 private $charid;
 private $userid;
 private $username;
 private $class;
 private $exp;
 private $money;
 private $attack;
 private $defense;
 private $hp;
 private $turns;


function __construct($data){
 $pdo = Connection::getInstance();

try {
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $char = $pdo->prepare("SELECT users.userid, users.username, characters.charid, characters.money, characters.attack, characters.defense, characters.class, characters.hp, characters.userid, characters.turns, characters.exp
                         FROM characters
                         JOIN users ON users.userid=characters.userid
                         WHERE username=?");
  $char->execute(array($data));
  $res = $char->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  $this->charid = $res[0]['charid'];
  $this->userid = $res[0]['userid'];
  $this->username = $res[0]['username'];
  $this->class = $res[0]['class'];
  $this->exp = $res[0]['exp'];
  $this->money = $res[0]['money'];
  $this->attack = $res[0]['attack'];
  $this->defense = $res[0]['defense'];
  $this->hp = $res[0]['hp'];
  $this->turns = $res[0]['turns'];

}
catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e;
 }
}


public function __get($property) {
 if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
  return $this->$property;
 }
}

public function __set($property, $value) {
 if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
  $this->$property = $value;
 }
return $this;
 }
}
```

Comment: the best practice is to separate your logic code, make you method have a one job, either was a query or anything else

Comment: Thanks, editing now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) , this is for methods as for objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

And it is also advised to avoid using magic setters and getters. And same goes for singletons.

A constructor shouldn't actually contain any logic, because it make the code quite hard to test. Instead your class constructor should expect the connection as a parameter and perform the logic in a separate method. Kinda like this:

```
class Character 
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) 
    {
        $this->connection = $pdo;
    }

    public function populateByUsername($data) 
    {
        // come code
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT us ....");
        $statement->execute(array($data));
        $data = $char->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // more code
    }
}
```

To improve the code  further, I would recommend actually separating the SQL code from the entity's logic (in your example - character). The best approach for that would be use of [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern - it basically means that you have two classes - one for entity and one for sql parts. It ends up looking kinda like this:

```
$char = new Character;
$char->setUsername($username);

$mapper = new CharacterMapper($pdo);
$mapper->fetchByUsername($char);
```

In this case the mapper class take your entity, uses a getter to extract the username, calls the SQL and then puts the data in the character object. Later, when you get more familiar with OOP, you will also learn  to be able to call multiple mapper on the same entity, when necessary (for example, you can set it up so that there is a separate mapper for cache and separate for db .. you call the cache mapper first, and if it fails, you call the db mapper).

Answer (score 0):

The downside with this is your 'Character' class constructor would be tightly coupled to your database. Which means there would be no other way to initialize your 'Character' except with getting data from the DB. You won't be able to initialize it with another source (e.g. XML files) or initialize it with test data for the purposes of unit testing.

What I would recommend is to separate the query, into something like a 'InitializationProvider' (it's just an example because I'm not sure about your app's logic). Then you could have different types of InitializationProviders like DBInitializationProvider, XMLInitializationProvider, etc. that would be dynamically injected into your Character class.

It's up to you though if that kind of flexibility would be required in the future.